# How to delete files from external storage if application gets uninstalled in android

Tags: android

In my application i stored PDF files into external storage.My requirement is, need to delete all files from SD card, if application gets uninstall.

Thanks,
AA.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, unless you have another application installed on the phone.

`ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` intent will be sent out to all receivers except for your own.

> Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been removed
>   from the device. The data contains the name of the package. The
>   package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED